# What is a voltage-controlled differential current source & how do you simulate it in simulink?

Tags: logic-gates, differential

I am trying to achieve the same circuits designed in this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05064
by simulating it in simulink, yet I can't seem to understand what it is referring to by saying voltage-controlled differential current source (VCDCG) (I am not an electrical engineer btw).

The author states that he needs this VCDCG component to make 0 voltage an unstable point and push the circuit values to +1 or -1 wherever we add this VCDCG.

All I understand is that it measures the voltage wherever we connect it and generates current based on that (typical current source behaviour) and is attached to a ground/electrical reference at the other end.

The author states in his book "Memcomputing Fundementals and applications" that "When the current source depends on the voltage input, then they are called voltage-controlled. When the current source magnitude varies in time according to voltage differences, it is called
a voltage-controlled differential current source" supposedly referencing something in Horowitz's 3rd edition book.

But there is nothing with the same name, and I don't know what to map it and what it looks like if what he meant was something like some kind of an op-amp (goes beyond my knowledge on how they are used).

**In short my question is:**

What is this VCDCG in terms of a circuit/component, what are the constants needed (if any exist) to operate this component and what does it connect to (in every terminal), so that I can simulate it in simulink?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a pair of independent current sources (one source, one sink) controlled by the same voltage? One has transconductance \$g\$, and the other has transconductance \$-g\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f50RZq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I tried it but it had no effect on the circuit in any way, it is the same as adding one voltage controlled current source too.
I think he wants it to fight back when the circuit goes to 0 or push it away in some way (not sure how).
If it helps, he says it acts as a negative inductor near 0 volt, and an inductor in series with a DC voltage (+1V/-1V) near voltages +1 and -1 respectively